# Generalize point data to a reference vector grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have a point feature, each point has a floating value assigned. I have a square grid (polygon) feature overlapping the points. I want to assign a value to each grid cell equal to the sum of the points' value inside the cell. 
Something similar to Zonal Statistics tool (ArcGIS) that can use a point layer instead of a raster for input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Spatial Join:

1. Right-click polygon layer - Joins And Relates - Joins. Select Join data from another layer based on spatial location
2. Specify the Point layer
3. Select the first bullet (Each polygon is given a summary of the numeric attributes...) and check the Sum box
4. Specify an output location and click OK

[image]

The output polygons will have the sum of all numerical attributes of the points